I am trying to make my program save one image after passing some filters to it to a folder. OPENCV PYTHON3 JETSON NANO
I want to take pictures and put them in a folder after passing some filters to it. The problem I'm having is that whenever I take a second image or third etc, and try to save it to another directory, A very similar image to the one taken at the start is being saved to the new folder, and not an image taken just when I said so in the input.
I believe my program is taking lots of pictures at the start somewhere I do not know and then using those. Maybe it is a memory problem, as I am using a Jetson Nano and taking too many pictures in RAM is not easy for it
My code (Do not mind for the AI PARTS)
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, concatenate, Input
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import os
from time import sleep


path = os.getcwd()
forward = "fd"
right = "rt"
left = "lt"
right_rotate = "rtr"
left_rotate = "ltr"

forward_folder = f"{os.path.join(path, forward)}"
right_folder = f"{os.path.join(path, right)}"
left_folder = f"{os.path.join(path, left)}"
rotate_right_folder = f"{os.path.join(path, right_rotate)}"
rotate_left_folder = f"{os.path.join(path, left_rotate)}"

fol2abbrev = {forward_folder : forward, right_folder : right, left_folder : left, rotate_right_folder : right_rotate, rotate_left_folder : left_rotate}

folders = [forward_folder, right_folder, left_folder, rotate_right_folder, rotate_left_folder]
abbrev = [forward, right, left, right_rotate, left_rotate]
recording_number = 1

for element in abbrev:
    try:
        os.mkdir(element)
    except Exception as e:
        #print(e)
        pass
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#Instantiate cv2 cam (TAKES LESS NOW)
width = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

Images = np.empty((0, height, width))#set the image array to an empty one, with the shape of height width (To make the image shape)
labels = np.empty(0)
Lasers = np.empty((0, 5)) #Put 8 if 8 lasers in the end

def preprocess_image(image):
    # Grayscale
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Blur the image
    blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 4)

    # Sharpen the image
    kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                       [-1,  9, -1],
                       [-1, -1, -1]])
    sharpened_image = cv2.filter2D(blurred_image, -1, kernel)

    # Enhance contrast (optional)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=16.0, tileGridSize=(16, 16))
    contrast_enhanced = clahe.apply(sharpened_image)

    return contrast_enhanced

def image_sort(path):
    images = []
    for element in os.listdir(path):
        if ".jpg" in element:
            images.append(element)
    return images

def text_sort(path):
    texts = []
    for element in os.listdir(path):
        if ".txt" in element:
            texts.append(element)
    return texts

def folder_value(folder):
    if folder == forward_folder:
        return 0
    elif folder == right_folder:
        return 1
    elif folder == left_folder:
        return 2
    elif folder == rotate_right_folder:
        return 3
    elif folder == rotate_left_folder:
        return 4
    else:
        raise "Problem with folder, the value given is not equal to a valid folder adress stated above!"

def rec_image(folder, times=1):
        ret, image = cam.read() #THE CAMERA SHOULD BE CONNECTED DIRECTLY TO JETSON NANO
        image = preprocess_image(image)
        print(f"IMAGE is being saved to {folder}")
        cv2.imwrite(f"{folder}/{len(image_sort(folder))}.jpg",image)

def rec_lasers(folder, times=1):
        data = [1,2,3,4,5] #GET DATA FROM LASERS WITH JETSON NANO
        file = open(f"{folder}/{len(text_sort(folder))}.txt", "w")
        file.write(str(data))
        file.close()

def read_data(folder):
    global Images, labels, Lasers
    for i in range(len(image_sort(folder))):
        if i < len(image_sort(folder))-1:
            image = cv2.imread(f"{folder}{i+1}.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            Images = np.append(Images, [image], axis=0)
            labels = np.append(labels, folder_value(folder))
    for i in range(len(text_sort(folder))):
        if i < len(text_sort(folder))-1:
            data = open(folder+text_sort(folder)[i],"r")
            data = data.read().strip('][').split(', ')
            Lasers = np.append(Lasers, [data], axis=0) # Load the LASER DATA

def process_predictions(tensor): #Has to be a numpy tensor, because tensorflow const cannot append
    final_tensor = np.array([])
    for prediction in tensor:
        i = 1
        for choice in prediction:
            #print(choice)
            if round(float(choice)) == 1:
                final_tensor = np.concatenate((final_tensor, [i]))
                #print("IT SHOULD CONCAT 1!")
            else:
                i+=1
    return tf.constant(np.round(final_tensor))

def process_predictions_combined(predictions_image, predictions_laser):
    max_indices_image = np.argmax(predictions_image, axis=1)
    max_indices_laser = np.argmax(predictions_laser, axis=1)

    # Combine max indices for image and laser predictions
    combined_indices = np.column_stack((max_indices_image, max_indices_laser))

    return tf.constant(np.round(combined_indices))

def train():
    global Images, labels, Lasers

    for folder in folders:
        read_data(folder)

    Lasers = Lasers.reshape((Lasers.shape[0], Lasers.shape[1], 1))

    print(Images.shape)
    print(labels.shape)
    print(Lasers.shape)

    # Split the data
    train_images, test_images, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(Images, labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=21, stratify=labels)
    train_lasers, test_lasers, _, _ = train_test_split(Lasers, labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=21, stratify=labels)
    #print(f"LASERS : {train_lasers},{train_lasers.shape}")
    #Preprocess the data
    train_images = tf.expand_dims(train_images, axis=-1)
    test_images = tf.expand_dims(test_images, axis=-1)

    train_images = tf.cast(train_images, dtype=tf.int32)
    test_images = tf.cast(test_images, dtype=tf.int32)
    """
    train_lasers = tf.expand_dims(train_lasers, axis=-1)
    train_lasers = tf.expand_dims(train_lasers, axis=-1)"""

    train_lasers = tf.strings.to_number(train_lasers, out_type=tf.float64)
    test_lasers = tf.strings.to_number(test_lasers, out_type=tf.float64)

    train_labels = train_labels.astype(int)
    test_labels = test_labels.astype(int)
    laser_count = len(Lasers[0])

    print(f"LASERS : {train_lasers},{train_lasers.shape}")
    # CONV2D
    model1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(height, width, 1), name="Image_Input"),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, name="Image_1_Conv2D"),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="Image_2_Pooling2D"),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, name="Image_3_Conv2D"),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="Image_4_Pooling2D"),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, name="Image_5_Conv2D"),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),name="Image_6_Pooling2D"),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="Image_7_Flatten"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5,name="Image_8_Dropout"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)

    ])
    #CONV1D
    model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(laser_count, 1), name="Laser_Input"),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, name="Laser_Conv1D"),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="Laser_flatten"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)
    ])
    #FC MODEL
    model3 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=2, name="Combined_Input"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, name="Combined_1_Dense"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, name="Combined_2_Dense"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3, name="Combined_3_Dropout"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax, name="Combined_OUTPUT")
    ])
    #Compile and train the models
    model1.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                          loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, #Because it is category, mse is for numbers
                          metrics=["accuracy"])

    model2.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003),
                          loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, #Because it is category, mse is for numbers
                          metrics=["accuracy"])

    model3.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005),
                          loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, #Because it is category, mse is for numbers
                          metrics=["accuracy"])
    #print(train_labels)
    model1.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
    """print("Train lasers shape:", train_lasers.shape)
    print("Test lasers shape:", test_lasers.shape)
    """

    model2.fit(train_lasers, train_labels, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_lasers, test_labels))

    predictions_model1 = model1.predict(train_images)
    predictions_model2 = model2.predict(train_lasers)

    # Concatenate predictions along the axis corresponding to models (axis=1)
    """print(len(train_images)+len(train_lasers))
    print("LENGTH of predictions",len(predictions))
    print("LENGTH of predictions[0]", len(predictions[0]))
    print(np.array(predictions).shape)
    print(predictions)"""
    predictions = process_predictions_combined(predictions_model1, predictions_model2)
    print(predictions)
    print(len(predictions))
    #predictions = process_predictions(predictions)
    #predictions = predictions #- 1
    print(f"Predictions : {predictions.shape}")
    print(f"Labels : {train_labels.shape}")

    model3.fit(predictions-1, train_labels, epochs=25)

    model1.save("models/2DCNN")
    model2.save("models/1DCNN")
    model3.save("models/FCNN")
    return model1, model2, model3


def predict(images, lasers):
    sleep(1)

    predictions_model1 = model1.predict(images)
    predictions_model2 = model2.predict(lasers)
    combined = process_predictions_combined(predictions_model1, predictions_model2)
    combined = combined - 1
    print(combined, combined.shape)

    pred3 = model3.predict(combined)
    print(pred3)
    print(pred3.argmax())
    return pred3.argmax()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        if cam.isOpened():
                while True:
                        main = input("1(fd), 2(rt), 3(lt), 4(rtr), 5(ltr), 6(Train), 7(predict)")
                        #Instead of input, get values from recv
                        #Channel 1 to fwd
                        #Channel 2 to rt and lt (depends on the number)
                        #Channel 3 constant (set drone to hover / constant throttle)
                        #Channel 4 to rtr and ltr (depends on number)

                        if main == "1":
                            rec_image(forward_folder, recording_number)
                            rec_lasers(forward_folder, recording_number)
                        elif main == "2":
                            rec_image(right_folder, recording_number)
                            rec_lasers(right_folder, recording_number)
                        elif main == "3":
                            rec_image(left_folder, recording_number)
                            rec_lasers(left_folder, recording_number)
                        elif main == "4":
                            rec_image(rotate_right_folder, recording_number)
                            rec_lasers(rotate_right_folder, recording_number)
                        elif main == "5":
                            rec_image(rotate_left_folder, recording_number)
                            rec_lasers(rotate_left_folder, recording_number)
                        elif main == "6":
                            model1, model2, model3 = train()
                        elif main == "7":
                            predict()

In the name == "main" you can see I only call the function rec_image(folder) once per option, but it somehow records more than once, maybe it is in the rec_image() function, in cam.read(), or maybe in preprocess_image(). I do not know why it does not take an image each time
I have tried using another python file and importing this one. Trying to use only the rec_image() function it does work however importing the whole file into another one and using the whole if name == "main" it does not

What, exactly, is the camera device?  If it is a streaming device, then what you say is quite possible.  Perhaps you should do two cam.read() calls -- one to throw away what's in the stream, and one to hopefully catch a live image.  If that still doesn't work, you may need to spawn off a thread to do cam.read() calls in an infinite loop, and save the most recent image in a global.

the usual solution is to keep a thread to keep reading. I would +1 that recommendation. my usual recipe: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40 -- an ugly hack is to set some buffer to 0, which may still not remove enough of the latency because you only gained control over one of potentially many buffers that are involved in the data flow
